# How can I create a formula for proportional scale in geometric nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

[image]

How do I create a formula so that the scale changes and immediately becomes the same?
For example:
I set the scale to 2 and in another transform I changed it to 0.5 so that it would become the original one.
4 by 0.25.
8 by 0.125.

Comment: just use multiply with 1 divided by value.

Comment: Could you describe it in more detail? Pls

Comment: if you provide blend file, i will provide the solution

Comment: https://we.tl/t-3zqXRYzcKV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hopefully this is what you want.

So the right cube scales "normal", the left cube scales 2 times so that it keeps its size.

Please note that this will not work for scale equal to zero.

Comment: thank you very much!! It works

Comment: you are welcome